# How to generate extra rows beneath main ones in Excel based on values from cells in first column

Tags: vba, excel

Like the title says, i need some sort of macro or vba script, or whatever microsoft excel uses in order to generate a number of extra rows under a main one in Excel, number based on value from cells in first column. The sheet looks sorta like this:

```
    Value1     Description1 Email1 Name1 etc  
    Value2     Description2 Email2 Name2 etc   
   ....                       
    Value N
```

Underneath each row I need to generate new rows based on the values from the first cell and autocomplete the remaining row with the information from the main one. The values form column one follow one of these rules:
1. There can be empty cells, in which case, nothing happens.
2. There can be one 10 digits number, in which case, again, nothing happens.
3. There can be more than one 10 digits numbers, separated by commas, which would then be required to be extracted on different rows.
4. There can be something like "1234567890 - 1234567893", in which case I would need to generate 4 new rows, starting with values ending in 0,1,2,3.
5. There can be a range from 4) and then a new number, separated by commas, ex: "value - value, value" (still 10 digits numbers btw).
6. And finally, 2 ranges of values, like "value - value, value - value".

One important thing to mention is that the cells from the first column are always marked as text, even if the content of the cell is a number.

I reached my breaking point with this. I am an excel novice and got this task as part as my new job. So its make it or break it time. Please.

Final example:

```
1000000000 - 1000000003                         Text1  a@a.com  Joe        
1000000000                                      Text1  a@a.com  Joe       
1000000001                                      Text1  a@a.com  Joe          
1000000002                                      Text1  a@a.com  Joe       
1000000003                                      Text1  a@a.com  Joe        
2000000000, 2000000002                          Text2  b@b.com  Bob         
2000000000                                      Text2  b@b.com  Bob                
2000000002                                      Text2  b@b.com  Bob
3000000000- 3000000002, 3000000005- 3000000007  Text3  c@c.com  John 
3000000000                                      Text3  c@c.com  John                
3000000001                                      Text3  c@c.com  John 
3000000002                                      Text3  c@c.com  John   
3000000005                                      Text3  c@c.com  John 
3000000006                                      Text3  c@c.com  John 
3000000007                                      Text3  c@c.com  John
```

Comment: Nice software specification. What can you show in terms of original effort toward solving the problem?

Answer (score 1):

When inserting rows, always start at the bottom and work toward the top. Similarly, after splitting the pieces work from the last to the first piece.

Store the remainder of the values in a variant array to be used to fill in the repeated values for each new row.

**[Module1 (Code)](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/generate%20extra%20rows%20beneath%20main%20ones%20in%20Excel%20based%20on%20values%20from%20cells%20in%20first%20column.xlsb)**

```
Option Explicit

Sub insertRows()
    Dim rw As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim vals As Variant, vtmp As Variant, vtmp2 As Variant

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For rw = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
            If CBool(InStr(1, .Cells(rw, 1).Value2, Chr(44))) Or _
               CBool(InStr(1, .Cells(rw, 1).Value2, Chr(45))) Then
                vals = .Cells(rw, 1).Resize(1, 4).Value2
                vtmp = Split(Replace(vals(1, 1), Chr(32), vbNullString), Chr(44))
                For i = UBound(vtmp) To LBound(vtmp) Step -1
                    vtmp2 = Split(vtmp(i), Chr(45))
                    For j = Int(Right(vtmp2(UBound(vtmp2)), 1)) To Int(Right(vtmp2(LBound(vtmp2)), 1)) Step -1
                        .Cells(rw + 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert
                        .Cells(rw + 1, 1).Resize(1, 4) = vals
                        .Cells(rw + 1, 1) = Int(Left(vtmp2(UBound(vtmp2)), 9) & j)
                        With .Cells(rw + 1, 1).Resize(1, 4).Interior
                            .Pattern = xlSolid
                            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
                            .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
                            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
                        End With
                    Next j
                Next i
                'optionally delete the original row
                '.Rows(rw).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next rw
    End With

End Sub
```

I have left some commented code in case you wanted to remove the original row.

---

[image: insertRows_10_digits]
                      <sup>Sample data before insertRows()</sup>

[image: insertRows_10_digits_after]
                      <sup>Sample data after insertRows()</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much, you are a job saver!